# Best examples of iphone and ipad app that differ? (Comparison of iphone & ipad apps)

Tags: design, iphone, ipad, comparison

I am studying the UX of iphone and their equivalent ipad apps. Does anyone have good examples of designs that differ because of the distinctive user experience that the two devices provide?

Answer (score 2):

Spotify for iPhone works like a charm and users have learnt how to use them. Then there where this iPad app which completely destroyed the user experience and does not work as expected. Users tend to play music on iPad but administer playlists on iPhone. The iPad app lacks a lot of featured, you'd perceived being there.

This is an excellent study object of what not to do on iPad apps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, the biggest difference was the the approach for master-detail design. On the iPhone, since there is lack of space, the details would appear on the "Next" screen while on the iPad it was plain master-detail usage.

Take this (old) example: 
[image]

You can sometimes  even see this difference on the iPad holding it horizontally or vertically.

This is fundamental on many iPhone vs. iPad apps:
Mail, Youtube, Dropbox, Messages... and even the Settings!

For more research I'd try Productivity apps (maybe Keynotes and Pages) and Creativity (sketch and edit photos) since these could really benefit from the extra canvas size on the iPad.